# jQuery stop animate if condition

Tags: jquery, resize, scroll

I'm building a website using different **@media (min-width, max-width)** to show the website perfect on major device.

I have a menu that follow the top of the screen on scroll and this is the jQuery code:

```
var win_width = $(window).width();

        if (win_width >= 751) {
            var el = $('div.menu-header');
            var elpos_original = el.offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var elpos = el.offset().top;
                var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
                var finaldestination = windowpos;
                if(windowpos<elpos_original) {
                    finaldestination = elpos_original;
                    el.stop().css({'top':0});
                } else {
                    el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination-elpos_original+30},500);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It works fine but if I resize the window at 750 pixel I would like to stop this function and restore the **var el** to the original position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, function given to scroll will be invoked immediately whenever user will scroll

```
var el = $('div.menu-header'),
elpos_original = el.offset().top;
$(window).scroll (function() {
    var win_width = $(this).width();
      if (win_width >= 751) {
        var elpos = el.offset().top;
        var windowpos = $(this).scrollTop();
        var finaldestination = windowpos;
        if(windowpos<elpos_original) {
            finaldestination = elpos_original;
            el.stop().css({'top':0});
        } else {
            el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination-elpos_original+30},500);
        }
    } else {
         $(this).resize(); // calling to handle declared below. 
    }
}).resize( function() { 
       // Check when resizing whether size is at most 750
       // and restore original position;
       if( $(this).width() <=750 ) { 
          el.stop().css( "top", "0" )
       }
} )
```

Comment: There is an error, when I try to resize the window seems to have infinite height.

Comment: Edited, original pos must be preserved. Take a look

Comment: Edited again. Can you post sample on eg jsfiddle.net? I can't  to check what I write:)

Comment: Now it work, just to edit this: el.stop().css( "top", elpos_original ) to: el.stop().css( "top", '0' ).
Thanks for your time.